# Why doesn't incrementing Nullable<int> throw an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

Could you please explain, why does Console.WriteLine write empty line (`Console.WriteLine(null)` give me compilation error) and why there isn't NullReferenceException (even `a+=1` shouldn't raise it)?

```
int? a = null;
a++; // Why there is not NullReferenceException? 
Console.WriteLine(a); // Empty line
```

Comment: All of the three operators `++`, `+=`, and `+` have lifted variants. Therefore the statements `a++;`, `a += 1;`, and `a = a + 1;` are all allowed. Each produce `null` (no exception thrown) if `a` is initially `null`.

Comment: `NullReferenceException`? but `int?` is not a `Reference`, it's just an `int` that can take `null` value

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You're observing the effects of a *lifted operator*.

From section 7.3.7 of the C# 5 specification:

> Lifted operators permit predefined and user-defined operators that operate on non-nullable value types to also be used with nullable forms of those types. Lifted operators are constructed from predefined and user-defined operators that meet certain requirements, as described in the following:
>
> - For the unary operators `+  ++  -  --  !  ~`
>   a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand and result types are both non-nullable value types. The lifted form is constructed by adding a single `?` modifier to the operand and result types. The lifted operator produces a null value if the operand is null. Otherwise, the lifted operator unwraps the operand, applies the underlying operator, and wraps the result.

So basically, `a++` in this case is an expression with a result of `null` (as an `int?`) and the variable is left untouched.

When you call

```
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

that's being boxed into `object`, which converts it to a null reference, which is printed as an empty line.

Comment: Is there a way to print "null" without using `Console.WriteLine(a == null ? "null" : a)`?

Comment: @Cole Johnson:  Console.WriteLine(a ?? "null");   :)

Comment: @DavidChappelle When `a` is of type `int?`, I would say `a ?? "null"` finds no common type for the two operands. You need a hint that `object` is the common type. So cast either operand to that. The `a` will be boxed. For example `((object)a) ?? "null"` or `a ?? (object)"null"`.

Comment: super. can you link to the spec? can we define this when we overload operators in our own classes?

Comment: @teabaggs: I can't easily link right now, and the link would just be to a Word doc (which you can find easily enough with a search). You automatically get lifted operators when you define operator overloads, where appropriate.

Answer (score 116):

Jon's answer is correct but I would add some additional notes.

> Why does `Console.WriteLine(null)` give a compilation error?

There are 19 overloads of `Console.WriteLine` and three of them are applicable to a `null`: the one that takes a `string`, the one that takes a `char[]` and the one that takes an `object`. C# cannot determine which of these three you mean, so it gives an error. `Console.WriteLine((object)null)` would be legal because now it is clear.

> why does `Console.WriteLine(a)` write an empty line?

`a` is a null `int?`. Overload resolution chooses the `object` version of the method, so the `int?` is boxed to a null reference.  So this is basically the same as `Console.WriteLine((object)null)`, which writes an empty line.

> Why there is not `NullReferenceException` on the increment?

Where's the null **reference** that you are worried about?  `a` is a null `int?` which is not a reference type to begin with! Remember, nullable value types are **value types**, not **reference types**, so don't expect them to have reference semantics unless they are boxed to a reference type.  There is no boxing in the addition.

Answer (score 0):

> Are You incrementing null???

```
int? a = null;
a++;
```

This statement simply means `null++` i.e. null+1.

As per this document, A nullable type can represent the correct range of values for its underlying value type, plus an additional null value.A Nullable, pronounced "Nullable of Int32," can be assigned any value from -2147483648 to 2147483647, or it can be assigned the null value

Here you are incrementing null, then also it will become null value not 0 or any other integer.

> Why it prints blank instead of error??

when you print a nullable type with null value it prints blank instead of error because you are printing a variable i.e. value of a memory location. which maybe null or any integer.

But when you try to print null using `Console.WriteLine(null)`, as null is not a variable, so it doesn't refer to any memory location. And hence it gives error `"NullReferenceException"`.

> Then how can you print any integer using `Console.WriteLine(2);` ??

In this case, 2 will gets in memory at temporary location, and the pointer points to that memory location to print.