# Shorthand JavaScript equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a nullable byte I want to increment or set to 0 depending on if it's null, like this:

```
if (TheNullableByte == null)
{
   TheNullableByte = 0;
}
else
{
   TheNullableByte = TheNullableByte++;
}
```

In javascript I'd write it like this:

```
TheNullableByte = (TheNullableByte) ? TheNullableByte++ : 0;
```

Is there something similar in C#?

Comment: `TheNullableByte = TheNullableByte++;` looks at least dubious. Perhaps `TheNullableByte = TheNullableByte+1;` makes more sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be the shortest construct possible:

```
TheNullableByte = ++TheNullableByte ?? 0;
```

Using the [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

*Small explanation:*

Assuming `TheNullableByte` is a `byte?` variable without a value (it is `null`) `++TheNullableByte` does not change its value (the expression result is `null`). At the end you have either `0` (if it was `null`) or the value incremented by one.

Comment: `TheNullableByte++` is evaluated before the null-coalescing check, and will throw an exception if `TheNullableByte` is `null`

Comment: @CoolBots Just tried on [CSharpPad](http://csharppad.com/) and works fine. Are you sure about that?

Comment: you're right - I expected this result: *Operator '++' is ambiguous on an operand of type '<null>'*, as in `null++`. I don't understand why this works - per documentation, `byte?  = null;` unboxes to `null` on subsequent operation.

Comment: This question addresses why the *++ Operator* works in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172558/why-doesnt-incrementing-nullableint-throw-an-exception

Comment: Also, I just tested this myself as well, when `TheNullableByte` has a value it won't increment unless you do this `TheNullableByte = ++TheNullableByte ?? 0;` I guess the the original value of TheNullableByte is saved temporarily before being passed back? I sure thought it wouldn't make a difference since it's incrementing the value we are assigning to itself.

Comment: @MarkRucker Thanks for the tip, just fixed the answer.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma thanks for the SO link, very helpful! I didn't know about *lifted operators*. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Awesome piece of code. Under no conditions I'd like to see it anywhere close to code I write so.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the [`Nullable<T>.HasValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
TheNullableByte = TheNullableByte.HasValue ? TheNullableByte + 1 : 0;
```